# Как по ajax принять json ответ от laravel?

Tags: ajax, json, http, laravel, xmlhttprequest

Дело  в том, что в ответ я получаю заголовки и сам json. Выглядит это примерно так

```
return response()->json([ 'somedata' => 1 ]);
```

В js так

```
$.get('/page', function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

Результат:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json

{"somedata":"1"}
```

Соответственно, js такое распарсить не может. Нагуглить ничего не удалось. Да и, кажется, раньше такого поведения не наблюдалось.

Comment: console.log(data.body)?

Comment: @АндрейТаланин `undefined`

Comment: т.е. data - вообще не объект?

Comment: @АндрейТаланин, да, он такой и приходит, каким я показал в "результате". То есть это просто текст от сервера. По идеи заголовки сообщают браузеру, что это, их не должно быть в конечном итоге видно.

Comment: С другими json запросами такая же ситуация?

Comment: Попробуйте http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @АндрейТаланин Это все не имеет значение. Такое ощущение, что там просто невалидные заголовки. Если я делаю просто `return json_encode(['somedata' => '1']);`, то все нормально. Но так делать я не буду.

Comment: А вы говорите, что раньше не наблюдалось: это в этом же проекте работало и вдруг перестало, или как?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43930/discussion-between---and-fortael).

Comment: @АндрейТаланин В этом проекте, на laravel, я еще не использовал ajax. Но обычное для меня поведение ajax, это когда приходит только тело ответа, без заголовков. Вернее заголовки приходят, но они для браузера и в js ответ они уже не попадают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в типизации php7.

```
public function index() : string {
    return response()->json([ 'somedata' => 1 ]);
}
```

Без `: string` все работает замечательно. Заголовки больше не попадают в тело ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Для декодирования json используйте jQuery.parseJSON

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
for(i in result){
alert(result[i]);       
}
```

Результат 1 в алерте

Comment: Не сработало бы, ибо в теле ответа были заголовки.